# Is there a way to obtain the list of client machines which connect to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, amazon-rds

We would like to monitor the list of client machines (IP addresses, login, logout times) which connect (e.g. via ssh) into a Amazon EC2 | RDS instance

Answer (score 2):

The `last -iF` command is the one you want.

This list also includes local logins (at the console) as well as reboots.  The actual data is stored in `/var/log/wtmp`.

If you want to know the last time each user logged in, try `lastlog`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current connected machines with

```
 netstat -tnp|grep ':22'|grep sshd|awk '{print $5}'|cut -d':' -f1
```

the login, logut times of past clients you can get from the logs of your ssh server.